# App Store Apple ID review Information give ID already exist error

Tags: apple-id

I have an apple id which I am trying to use to install apps on my IPad.

When I go to app store and click get -> install then it asks me to login. I provide id and password and then it shows me a popup saying "This Apple ID has not yet been used in the iTunes Store - Tap Review to sign in, then review your account information"

Once I click Review it would show me a form Confirm Country -> Agree to Conditions and then Account. Here I am bound to fill mandatory inputs which include password etc. Once I fill and click Next it give me following error:

"This email address is already in use or you may already have an Apple ID associated with this email address. Please try again or sign in using your existing Apple ID"

I am stuck in this deadlock and can not find a way to get out of it. Can somebody please tell me how to get out of it?

Answer (score 1):

I have sorted out the problem by signing into itunes. For some reason iTunes setup a new apple id and corrects the link. Itunes also asked me to review information when I logged into first time but it did not get into any deadlock.